# Send SMS through ADB to phone

Tags: android, sms, adb, galaxy

I want to send test SMS messages from my PC via adb, to the phone. Is this possible? I've seen scripts to automate sending SMS *from* the phone, but I want to simulate SMS messages to the phone. I was able to do this via the emulator by telneting to it. Is there something I can do with a real phone (Galaxy Nexus). I do'nt have the development phone hooked up to phone service; I want this to be directly from the comptuer to the phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending a SMS on Android through ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580199/sending-a-sms-on-android-through-adb)

Answer (score 2):

You could develop a small application that receives an Intent and which is capable of sending an SMS accordingly to the received data.

You need to declare a custom `<intent-filer>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and bind a `BroadcastReceiver` on that Intent. So you will be advertised everytime an Application issues *this* Intent.

On the other side, use the command line to send intents to your VMs using :

```
adb shell am start -a broadcast com.messenger.sms.send -e message my_message
```

In the `BroadcastReceiver`, the extra data will be accessible through a call to :

```
intent.getExtras().getString("message");
```

You can also find [here](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/ADB_Shell_Command_Reference) more thorough examples on what you can do using `am`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another cell phone with actual service?

If only a rough simulation is what you're looking for, I'd suggest you set up a [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com) account to receive texts from a Google Voice number via wifi, or just use something like [MightyText](http://mightytext.net/) to synchronize the sms messages/notifications from your activated phone with your deactivated development phone (over wifi).

I assume that MightyText will probably be the easiest and quickest to set up between the two.