# adb send SMS command does nothing on Android 10

Tags: adb

I have a C# application which executes adb command to send SMS.
It worked well on Android 8 (Samsung phone).

Untill recently I've upgraded my phone to Android 10.

The sending SMS command does nothing.

`>adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "0123456789" s16 "null" s16 "Hello" s16 "null" s16 "null"`

In the command line, it executes then returns an output:
*Result: Parcel(00000000    '....')*
but no SMS sent.

[image: adb send SMS command does nothing on Android 10]

Please help me to find where the problem is or any change since android 10.
Many thanks.

P/S: My reference source is: [Sending a SMS on Android through ADB - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580199/sending-a-sms-on-android-through-adb)

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of Googled and many tries...
...
It's strange but when I insert 2 SIMs on my **dual SIM phone** it works !
And when I have only 1 SIM inserted, it DOES NOT work !